# When running pdfplumber in python I got an error --> CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team

Tags: python, pdf, cryptography, pdfplumber

I'm using a Python script that extracts the text content of a PDF file using pdfplumber.

When running pdfplumber in python I got an error like this

```
CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team.
Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography and will be removed in a future release.

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
```

This is the python script

```
import pdfplumber
pdf = pdfplumber.open(file_path)

tables=pdf.pages[0].extract_table()
df = pd.DataFrame(tables[1::],columns=tables[0])
```

How to solve this error notification? because the python script is still running fine. Will it be a problem if this error is not removed?

Comment: It's a warning, not an error and it's pretty self-explanatory. Unless you upgrade your version of Python you may not be able to upgrade `cryptography` to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

You can supress this message several ways:

1. Upgrade your python. The most acceptable way, as the developers of Cryptography write that in future versions, they will stop supporting python 3.6.
2. Just supress this warning:

   `import warnings`

   `from cryptography.utils import CryptographyDeprecationWarning warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=CryptographyDeprecationWarning)`